# ¿Como importar un #include de otra carpeta en lenguaje c?

Tags: c

Estoy intentando importar un modulo o archivo de una carpeta a otra en lenguaje C (Como es común hacer en otros java, c#, etc). Como se pueden dar cuenta tengo el archivo State.h y State.c en la carpeta controllers, pero deseo importar a la carpeta src en el archivo GameOfLife.c ¿Como puedo hacerlo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: #include <GameOfLife.c>

Comment: Puedes intentar `#include "../controllers/State.h"`. Te recomendaria incluir la carpeta `controllers` dentro de `src/` y usar `#include "controllers/State.h"`.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono solo que había que agregar "../controllers/State.h"